# Does Scaleform now support AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, scaleform

Does Scaleform now support AS3?

Answer (score 3):

Supposedly they're working on AS3 now and will have it available by the end of the year.  They also claim to be optimizing the rendering engine to fully support Flash 9/10 effects in hardware, which will be super cool.

Their new CLIK Flash UI components were made by the same guy that made Adobe's Flash 9 components, Grant Skinner.  Basically it cuts down a huge amount of time/risk by providing a drag and drop ActionScript based UI widget set specially for game developers... it's pretty neat and probably very useful, esp since it's free with the kit.
https://www.scaleform.com/products/clik

I'm starting to dig into their new AMP memory/performance reporting tool and Flash Video support.  Looks like there's no more need to license Bink, which I'm quite happy about since that was never very impressive.  Leveraging integrating Flash Video is awesome for full screen video and special effects in UI.

Anyways, I'll let you know when I hear more about AS3.  So far we've been super happy with Scaleform's player, esp performance and memory of their new 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Scaleform supports AS3 now

http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/30745/New_Scaleform_GFx_40_Supports_ActionScript_3_Flash_10.php

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Scaleform added AS3 support in version 4.0.

Here are the official supported AS3 methods that Scaleform supports:
http://gameware.autodesk.com/documents/gfx_4.0_as3_extensions.pdf